# I want to have an 'else' statement on code using a 'for' and 'if' statement to iterate trough a list to find an item that is a key to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a 'for' statement then an 'if' statement to find an item from a list that is in a dictionary. I want the "Curious, tell me more" to only print once.

Here's how I expect the program to work:

```
input: i have a cat
output: Cats are the greatest animals in the world

Input:i do not like dogs 
Output: Dogs are boring

input:i love my pet
Output:Curious, tell me more
```

My current code:

```
Dict_1 = {'cat':'Cats are the greatest animals in the world','dog':'Dogs are boring'}
query = 0
while (not query=='quit'):
     query = input().split()
     for i in query:
          if i in Dict_1:
               query = Dict_1[i]
               print(query)
          else:
               print('Curious, tell me more')
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of `Dict_1`.

Comment: Watch the indentation (by the way)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the curious tell me more prints too many times, it prints the 'else' for every item in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another variable to store the answer and exit the loop once you have found the answer:

```
Dict_1 = {'cat':'Cats are the greatest animals in the world','dog':'Dogs are boring'}
query = 0
while (not query=='quit'):
     query = input().split()
     ans = None
     for i in query:
          if i in Dict_1:
               ans = Dict_1[i]
               break
     if ans is None:
          print('Curious, tell me more')
     else:
          print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `query = input().split()`, you're turning `query` into a list. Eg. if the user enters `cat dog`, query will be `['cat','dog']`.

So, instead of checking `query=='quit'` (which will never be true, because `query` is a list not a string), you should check if query *contains* `'quit'` with `'quit' in query`.

If you don't want to print `'Curious, tell me more'` when the user quits, then use an infinite `while` loop, and break the loop when `'quit'` is read.

You can generate a set containing the commands found in the query using set intersection: `commands_found = set(Dict_1.keys()) & set(query)`

Here's a working implementation:

```
Dict_1 = {'cat':'Cats are the greatest animals in the world','dog':'Dogs are boring'}
query = []
while True:
    query = input().split()
    if 'quit' in query:
        break
    commands_found = set(Dict_1.keys()) & set(query)
    if commands_found:
        for i in commands_found: print(Dict_1[i])
    else:
        print('Curious, tell me more')
```

Note that I'm initializing `query` as a list now with `query = []`.
Output:

```
I like my cat
Cats are the greatest animals in the world
I like my cat and dog
Cats are the greatest animals in the world
Dogs are boring
I like my racoon
Curious, tell me more
I want to quit
```

Comment: the output should not have Curious,tell me more ,if the first condition is met

Comment: should the user be able to put multiple commands in a single line or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to it to print only once, you could try setting a variable to true after printing "curious, tell me more". So the code should look like (based on glhr's answer)

```
Dict_1 = {'cat':'Cats are the greatest animals in the world','dog':'Dogs are boring'}
query = []
out = False
while not 'quit' in query:
    query = input().split()
    for i in query:
         if i in Dict_1:
             print(Dict_1[i])
         else:
             if not out:
                 print('Curious, tell me more')
                 out = True
```

If you want this to reset every time the user inputs a query, then move `out = False` into the while loop.

Comment: The `out` flag is completely unnecessary here. The code still prints `'Curious, tell me more'` only once if you remove the `out` flag.